# Take input string in c

Tags: c

To take input string in c, we can opt for 2 ways(**as per my knowledge please add more if i missing something**)

```
char name[10];
scanf(" %s",name); // First case
scanf("%[\n]s",name); // Second case
```

1st one will consider the string till the first blank space and 2nd will take complete sentence till the new line break as a string but to take input we need to improvise the 2nd statement as

```
scanf(" %[\n]s",name);
```

my question is what is extra spacing doing here ?
because sometime my compiler will behave normally even if i will remove the 's' from scanf statement and without extra spacing before '%' but sometime it wont work.

Comment: Why do people ask questions that can be answered simply by reading the documentation?

Comment: @nishant-kumar : I wonder the `s` at the end of `%[\n]s` makes a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079144/why-we-need-to-put-space-before-c Read the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177752/scanf-ns-a-vs-getsa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does space in scanf mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean)

Comment: There are differences and problems with both.  The more robust approach is to use neither.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: "sometime it wont work." is not that useful.  Posting input, output and expected output is useful.

Answer (score 1):

The space before the `%` operator will make it so that any white-space before the entered string is removed as well as whatever effect the format specifiers after the `%` operator have on the input.

Ex: "\n\t Hello World" entered with `" %[^\n]"` will be recorded as "Hello World".

Comment: Disagree with "The spacing will do nothing ..." .  The space in the format `scanf(" %[\n]s",name);` has an important impact: consume leading white-space.

Comment: @chux Remove or create whitespace?

Comment: "Remove or create whitespace?" is unclear as `scanf()` does not create white-space.  Perhaps re-phrase the question.

Comment: @chux Sorry, I meant to ask what you meant by "consume whitespace". If you can clarify, I will change my answer.

Comment: A `scanf()` white-space directive like `" "` consumes whitespace from `stdin`.  White-spaces characters are read, but not save anywhere.  This is often important before `"%[\n]"` to consume a previous entry's line-feed.

Comment: So, to clarify... With the space, all whitespace from the input would b deleted so "hello world" would become "helloworld"?@chux

Comment: Not quite.  With the space, all _leading_ white-space from the input would be consumed before specifier `"%[^\n]"`.  Input `"\n\t hello world"` be saved as "hello world" in `name[]`.

Comment: Okay @chux, Thank you for this. I will revise my answer. This is information that I did not know earlier.

Comment: when i am not putting space it is not taking input and printing some symbols, but after putting space it is working fine in my dev c compiler

Answer (score 0):

If white space character is left in first input stream and mistakenely read by next input `scanf`: to delete the white space character from input stream either use space before format string or use `fflush` (stdin) function.