# Assignment to expression with array type error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop, struct

in this program I try to sort customer savings descendingly. And I've tried to compile the code. And I'm still not to understand about pointer. There is an error with message "Assignment to expression with array type error". The target output of this program is tend to be the sorted customers(with their names, and account numbers). I've search in the internet about that error. But I still don't get the solution. Can someone help me to solve the error? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Data
{
  long long int Savings[100], AccNo[100];
  char Name[100];
};

int main ()
{
  struct Data *ptr;
  int n, i, j, swap = 1, x, y;
  long long int max, min, temp;

  printf ("Enter number of customer(s) : ");
  scanf ("%d", &n);

  ptr = (struct Data *) malloc (n * sizeof (struct Data));

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf ("Enter customer %d", i + 1);
      printf ("\nName : ");
      getchar ();
      scanf ("%[^\n]s", &(ptr + i)->Name);
      printf ("Savings : ");
      scanf ("%d", &(ptr + i)->Savings);
      printf ("Account Number : ");
      scanf ("%d", &(ptr + i)->AccNo);
      printf ("\n");
    }

  //Sorting bubblesort
  for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
      for (y = 0; y < (n - x - 1); y++)
    {
      if ((ptr + y)->Savings > (ptr + y + 1)->Savings)
        {
          temp = (ptr + y)->Savings;
          (ptr + y)->Savings = (ptr + y + 1)->Savings;
          (ptr + y + 1)->Savings = temp;
        }
    }
    }

  //Print sorted
  printf ("\n Sorted customers are (:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
      printf ("%s\n", (ptr + i)->Name);
      printf ("%d\n", (ptr + i)->Savings);
    }
  free (ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error message came with a line number, inn'it?

Comment: And where does this error occur?

Comment: Also, I dont think, `Savings` and `AccNo` need to be arrays.

Comment: `temp = (ptr + y)->Savings;` is wrong: `temp` is `long long` but the r-side is `struct Data *`.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s"` will attempt to read a literal factual `'s'`. The 's' does not belong in the conversion string

Comment: The error occur in `(ptr + y)->Savings = (ptr + y + 1)->Savings;` and `(ptr + y + 1)->Savings = temp;` @PaulOgilvie

Comment: In the bubble-sort algorithm you're trying to assign the array `long long int Savings[100]` to a simple `long long int temp`. Surely the bubble-sort example you used as base for your code worked with object pointers, assigning pointers to pointers, but you are mixing arrays and single variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to compile your code with warnings enabled, the will guide
   you through debugging step by step. Try to eliminate one, and
   compile again. In GCC for example, you would use `-Wall` flag.
2. The numerical fields of your struct should be just numbers, not
   arrays. Moreover, having their type as `long long int` seems a bit
   too much, but I leave that on you.
3. Having `(ptr + y)->Savings` to access the `y`-th element of an array
   of structs and the its field names `Savings` is technically correct,
   but it's much more cleaner (thus increases readability and
   maintainability) to write `ptr[y].Savings`. That is a general rule,
   applying to the rest of your code.
4. I believe the above led you to make two syntactical errors when you
   were reading the numerical data of the customers with `scanf()`,
   since you know that an integer in general needs the `&` operator. If
   you had used the clean approach from the start, you wouldn't made
   those, I believe.
5. For `long long int` use the `%lld` format specifier, not just `%d`.
6. In Bubblesort, when you find elements that need to be swapped, then
   swap the whole elements, not just their `Savings`s. I recommend
   creating a function to do that.
7. `scanf("%[^\n]s"` doesn't make much sense, I would change it to
   `scanf("%99s"`, where 99 is the maximum size of your string, minus
   one. Read more in the 2nd paragraph in [scanf(“%[^\n]s”,a) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536900/2411320).

Putting everything together, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Data {
    long long int Savings, AccNo; // these should be numbers, not arrays
    char Name[100];
};

void swap(struct Data* a, struct Data* b) {
    struct Data tmp;
    tmp.Savings = a->Savings;
    tmp.AccNo = a->AccNo;
    strcpy(tmp.Name, a->Name);

    a->Savings = b->Savings;
    a->AccNo = b->AccNo;
    strcpy(a->Name, b->Name);

    b->Savings = tmp.Savings;
    b->AccNo = tmp.AccNo;
    strcpy(b->Name, tmp.Name);
}

int main() {
    struct Data *ptr;
    int n, i, x, y;

    printf("Enter number of customer(s) : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    ptr = malloc (n * sizeof(struct Data)); // do not cast malloc

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter customer %d", i+1);
        printf("\nName : ");
        getchar();
        scanf("%99s", ptr[i].Name); // ptr is a pointer, but now you want to actually use it as an array, so use '.'
        printf("Savings : ");
        scanf("%lld", &ptr[i].Savings); // needs &, just like you did for 'n'. USe `%lld' for long lont int as the format specifier.
        printf("Account Number : ");
        scanf("%lld", &ptr[i].AccNo);   // needs &, just like you did for 'n'. USe `%lld' for long lont int as the format specifier.
        printf("\n");
    }

    //Sorting bubblesort
    for (x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < n - x - 1; y++) // you don't need paranetheses in the stop condition
        {
            if (ptr[y].Savings > ptr[y + 1].Savings)
            {
                swap(&ptr[y], &ptr[y + 1]); // swap the whole element, not just its savings
            }
        }
    }

    //Print sorted
    printf("\nSorted customers are:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", (ptr+i)->Name);
        printf("%lld\n", (ptr+i)->Savings);
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output (with relevant input):

```
Sorted customers are:
George
1
Babis
3
Theodor
20
```

PS: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Comment: Thank you very much!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SALOMO welcome to Stackoverflow! You posted a question with an MCVE, which is a very good thing! Next time, indent your code, too, +1! ;)